# Code of conduct top banner for localized sites

Tags: support, bug, localization, code-of-conduct

As far as I see the top banner with Code of Conduct notice (open the site with browser's private mode on) only visible on [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) and [Русский язык Stack Exchange](https://rus.stackexchange.com/):

> [image: esSO]

The rest localized sites don't have it:

- [スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/)
- [Stack Overflow em Português Meta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/)
- [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/)

> [image: ruSO]

Is it intentional or bug?